# Syntax error: missing 'integer' ao criar stored procedure em MySQL

Tags: mysql

Ao tentar criar a stored procedure abaixo, recebo o erro do título na
linha que contem: kill nID;
O que estou fazendo de errado:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ClearDB//

CREATE PROCEDURE ClearDB()
BEGIN
DECLARE nID, bCursor int;
DECLARE cursorQuery CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT ID
    FROM information_schema.processlist
    WHERE `TIME` > 1200;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bCursor = 1;

OPEN cursorQuery;
SET bCursor = 0;

WHILE bCursor = 0 DO
    FETCH cursorQuery INTO nID;
    kill nID;
END WHILE;

CLOSE cursorQuery;
END //
DELIMITER;
```